# Java Webservice based on Object

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, apache-axis

I'm using web services and I want to step it up a notch. I'm using Axis2 with JAX-WS. I'm thinking of transfering objects instead of `String[]`. After I googled a bit, I found that JAXB is the right support to do this.

However, everytime I want to add a modelclass that needs to be transferred, I need to do a lot of work (to shut up about all the annotations where I can make mistakes). So I thought it would be easier to abstract this a bit.

I was thinking of creating web services using the `Object` type. I can then use methods as `addObject(Object object)`, `removeObject(Object object)`, `retrieveObject()`. This means my server needs to handle incomming objects. If I then add a new model class, I just need to catch it at server end. My client will need to include the model classes causing some redundancy but I'm OK with that. I have the feeling that Java cannot support my idea at this momemnt. At least JAX-WS & JAXB technologies.

Can you guys tell me if I'm right or wrong about this, if this is a good idea or not and if so, maybe point me into the right direction on how to fix this (even if it means using another technology)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: netbeans has a wizard that will create model classes for you

Comment: Normally it's best to have typed domain models for your Web Service.  The WS for creating a purchase order takes an instance of `PurchaseOrder`, and the find customer call returns an instance of `Customer`.  Have typed parameters and return values allow for a good WSDL to be generated that makes it easier for users to interact with your service.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about the model classes and why does it take a lot of work to use them?

Comment: Model classes take a lot of work in a sense that you cannot write them as normal Java classes. If you can use a sort of abstraction layer (the Object type), then it's possible to rather plug-and-play with the classes. You only need to right a few lines additional to catch the new classes. It is then easier to program with multiple persons as well no matter what there skill level is.

Answer (score 0):

Your client won't need a model type, but you will have to serialize and deserialize your data when you send messages from your server to your client. I'm not sure if JAX-WS is different from JAX-RS, but if they are the same, then you can add annotations that mark whether or not you want to produce/consume json or xml.

Once you serialize your model to json, your client will have no problem reading your data.

Also, yest you can use object when creating request and response objects. In a webservice that I recently wrote I created a service response class similar to this

```
public class Response
{
    private Object data;
    private boolean success;

    public Response()
    {
        super();
    }

    //write getters and setters here

}
```

I think that I'm using the Object class in a similar fashion to what you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the info! If you use Object in your request and response objects, you probably still need to serialize and deserialize your data.. I thought of avoiding that by just copy-pasting my model class (or a simpler version of it) to the client as well.

Comment: @Tankske You will have to serialize and deserialize the data that you're sending no matter what.

Answer (score -1):

I definitely recommend you JAX-RS (implementing JAXB), in particular using the Jersey framework. It's usage is simple and allow you to marshall and unmarshall business objects.

Look at this [Jersey Example](http://magnus-k-karlsson.blogspot.ch/2013/01/rest-example-with-jersey-reference.html)

Hope it helps!